# How to use direct access permission to SD Card

Tags: java, android, sd-card, storage-access-framework

To write to SD CARD root we need to use the DOCUMENT_TREE Action of Storage Access Framework, but recently i have seen some apps that instead asks direct permission using a dialog, how can i use that dialog?
[image: The direct Access dialog]

Comment: Have a look at Storage Volume. Android 7+.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting